# Problem with width of auto-generated columns in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net

Maybe world peace would be easier, but I have a problem with the widths of auto generated columns when a DataGrid has no rows.  The column headings all squeeze up with no spacing between them.  I've tried adding the following CSS to no avail:

```
td.gridHeader
{
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right: 20px;        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive headings are rendered as <th> not <td>.

```
th.gridHeader
{
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right: 20px;        
}
```

I also assume you have applied <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" /> in the DataGrid markup. I didn't think people used DataGrids anymnore? or is it actually a GridView ?

Comment: Eish!  It is a DataGrid, but should be a GridView.  I've been using GridView in all my new code, and this is copied from old, and I just fell back into the habbit. [blush emoticon]