# Datagrid Headers all appearing in one column when CSS Style is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a datagrid in my screen display, defined as follows:-

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 380px; height: 300px">
    <asp:DataGrid id="ItemsGrid"
                  BorderWidth="1"
                  CellPadding="3"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                  runat="server">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="subHeader"></HeaderStyle>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="normalText"></ItemStyle >
    </asp:DataGrid>
</div>
```

This is displayed like this:-

[image: Display with HeaderStyle]

Without the HeaderStyle item the grid is displayed as I would expect:-

[image: Display without HeaderStyle]

(although the titles are styled wrongly). The CSS is thus:-

```
.subHeader
{
    clear:both;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I have tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179860/problem-with-width-of-auto-generated-columns-in-datagrid/179881#179881) but it doesn't make any difference.

**Edit**

As requested here is the HTML output, first for the version with the HeaderStyle entry:-

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 380px; height: 300px">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="1" id="ItemsGrid style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="subHeader">
        <td>Grade</td><td>Kurznamen</td><td>Discard&nbsp;Length</td>
    </tr><tr class="normalText">
        <td>13004</td><td>21CRNIMO2-2-2</td><td>23.17</td>
```

and without:-

```
                       <div style="overflow: auto; width: 380px; height: 300px">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="1" id="ItemsGrid" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>Grade</td><td>Kurznamen</td><td>Discard&nbsp;Length</td>
</tr><tr class="normalText">
    <td>13004</td><td>21CRNIMO2-2-2</td><td>23.17</td>
```

Comment: Can you share the difference in the HTML output after the control has been rendered?

Comment: @Steve, added the HTML as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `clear` and `float` rules and you should be good to go.

Also, in case you are not faimiliar with CSS, I recommend you to take a look on some sites like this: http://www.csstutorial.net/